# Why isn't my JSON function working?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have a function that is calling a php page on a remote server that is not reaching the server.  This function was working until I checked it today, when the customer told me that the counter was not updating. The param being passed in is a string, the alert shows the parameter ok, but the res.counterValue value is not coming back from the php page.

```
function getCounterJSON(param) {
    //alert('param: '+ param);
    $.getJSON('http://domainname/path/view.php?callback=?', 'counter=' + param, function(res) {
        //alert('return value '+res.counterValue);
        document.getElementById(param).innerHTML = '&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp' + res.counterValue + ' views';
    });
}
```

Callback function on the PHP page

```
{
    echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . "{'counterValue' : $counterValue}" . ')';
}
```

The counterValue is retrieving from the db ok too.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to execute a callback function with homemade json. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Not a solution, but you forgot the semi-colons here, "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".

Comment: @levi, that's what i'm trying to do.  What do you mean homemade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) instead of constructing your own JSON, like this:

```
echo json_encode(array('counterValue' => $counterValue));
```

Unless you use [JSONP](http://www.json-p.org/) (and you're not, since the `dataType` parameter of [jquery.Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is not set to `"jsonp"`), you don't need the callback.

Apart from that, the reason why your code doesn't work is that it separates strings with single quotes (`'`). According to the [JSON spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.5), strings must be enclosed with double quotes (`"`).

Also, you should use DOM functions (or their jQuery equivalents, such as `append`) instead of `innerHTML`.

Either way, HTML entities must be terminated with a semi-colon; you want `&nbsp;` (although some browsers will render the invalid `&nbsp` as well).

Comment: ahhh! still don't use `echo $_GET['callback'] . '(';` etc. this will vreak it.

Comment: @Neal Oops, that's indeed only needed for JSONP. Updated.

Comment: @phihag - I tried that json_encode line, but does not solve the problem. updated the non breaking space too.

Answer (score 2):

### Oy...

Just use `json_encode` on the server-side

```
echo json_encode(array('counterValue'=>$counterValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your real problem is that you aren't returning JSON and that's what `$.getJSON` expects.**  You are returning JavaScript.  Use `$.get` instead.

---

Everyone else is correct about encoding your json with `json_encode`, though.  Don't build json yourself.